# Azure Synapse Notebook: Join Large Cosmos Analytical Store With OnPrem->Blob Storage Data

Tags: apache-spark-sql, azure-data-factory, azure-cosmosdb, azure-synapse

There is a need for us to combine data from on-prem SQL and Cosmos container. Cosmos container has 100s of millions of documents. We are running a Azure Data Factory pipeline to load on-prem data into a csv file in storage. Same pipeline now runs a Synapse notebook (PySpark) to load data from Cosmos analytical store. Below are steps in notebook.

**1. Load on-prem(csv from storage) data into Data Frame (100k rows)**

**2. Connect to Cosmos analytical store**

```
df_cosmos = spark.read\
.format("cosmos.olap")\
.option("spark.synapse.linkedService", COSMOS_LINKED_SERVICE_NAME)\
.option("spark.cosmos.container", COSMOS_CONTAINER)\
.load()

df_cosmos.createOrReplaceTempView("c")
```

**3. Load data from Cosmos with query**

```
query = "Select c.pk, Sum(def) as def from c where <CLAUSE> Group By c.pk"
new_df = spark.sql(query)
```

**4. join DF from Step1 and DF from Step3 on PK**

Step no.3 and Step no.4 are taking more than 30 minutes. Is there a better approach to pull limited data from Cosmos analytical store by joining on-prem data frame rather than loading all data from analytical store and then applying join? Also I tried to run the query from step no.3 directly Synapse->Data-Sql and it takes lot of time.

We tried tweaking the query. Hoping to see if there are better alternatives to join the data between Azure analytical store and on-prem data.